# alias command that works in ssh too

Tags: ssh, bash, alias

I have some commands that I always use and they are rather hard to remember such as `lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`. I would like to create an alias for them that also applies when logged in via ssh on another server. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. You need to define your aliases on the other server.

Comment: After logging in to your remote host,  run a command that ssh's back to your local machine and collects the aliases from there:
`while read -r line; do "$line"; done < $(ssh localuser@localmachine "bash -ic alias")`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than defining your alias on the remote host, define a local alias for doing commands remotely. So instead of doing `$ ssh bar@foo` and then execute your `lsof -P -i -n | grep LISTEN` you do this on your local machine:

```
$ alias foolsof='ssh bar@foo "lsof -i -P -n" | grep LISTEN'
$ foolsof
```

Note that pipe and redirect can be tricky, the grep in the above command is executed on your local machine.

Comment: neat but I manage a lot of servers

Comment: Maybe you should look into Ansible then. The above could also be made into a function with an argument for user@host instead of hardcoded bar@foo.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make an alias but you can substitute shell variables into your unattended ssh sessions. I use it to define flags for things in scripts sometimes.

export THAT_COMMAND_YOU_LIKE="aptitude moo"

ssh user@server "sudo $THAT_COMMAND_YOU_LIKE "

Comment: same as above. I manage a lot of servers, this wouldn't help my scenario

Comment: if you manage a lot of servers you can use something like pssh to do the exact same thing en-mass. Aliases aren't allowed in shell scripts for safety reasons, but you can also substitute flags and stuff like that using shell variables, that you can define either in the script or in the command line before invoking the script.